# What is an Corporeal spell?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

The definition of [Incorporeal](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Incorporeal-Ex-) <sup>Pathfinder SRD</sup> declares

> An incorporeal creature has no physical body. It can be harmed only by other incorporeal creatures, magic weapons or creatures that strike as magic weapons, and spells, spell-like abilities, or supernatural abilities. It is immune to all nonmagical attack forms. Even when hit by spells or magic weapons, it takes only half damage from a corporeal source (except for channel energy). Although it is not a magical attack, holy water can affect incorporeal undead. **Corporeal spells and effects that do not cause damage only have a 50% chance of affecting an incorporeal creature.** Force spells and effects, such as from a magic missile, affect an incorporeal creature normally. *Emphasis mine*

What then is a corporeal spell?  Is it any spell except for force effects?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pretty much - it's any spell coming from a corporeal source (you know, a dude).

Now, it can get more complicated than that with things that aren't just incorporeal but also [ethereal](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/special-abilities#TOC-Ethereal). Only force spells affect them directly but there's a lot of spells (e.g. blink) that can be used to make someone ethereal/incorporeal and then it's fireball time.

Comment: Exactly. To put it simply; a corporeal spell has a large effect on the physical world, but not so much on the world of spirits and ghosts/other such primarily energy-based entities.